# Could you teach me a word which means do not change and stay as before?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Would you kindly teach me a word for the meaning below?

I am planning to replace a system consist of some computers and electrical devices connected by wires.

As some of the components are not so old, so we do not change those components.

Do you recomend me what to say to keep a part of  the system as before inspite of the other part is changed?

Comment: Some of the components can be ***re-used***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 'retain' as suggested above, eg:
We will be retaining some parts of the system, replacing older elements with new equipment.

Or, 
We will be updating older elements of our system with new equipment.

To explain that you are keeping only the newer parts you can say:

We will be retaining some *newer* parts of the system, replacing older elements with new equipment.

You can also use 'augment' meaning 'to add to':

We will be augmenting our *existing* system with some newer parts, replacing older elements with new equipment.

You can also say 'extend the life of'
We will be extending the life of our existing system by replacing some of the old parts with new.

Or 'renew'
We are renewing our existing system by replacing some old parts with new.

Or 'optimise'
We are optimising our existing system, renewing some older parts and adding some completely new elements.

Comment: I think our objective is to extend the life of our existing system. I learned a lot from your advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're very welcome, @Kojisugi! I used to work in IT 

Comment: Oh, that's why your advice looks hitting the nail on the head. I have to make a table to explain the system replacement plans describing which parts are going to be replaced and which are not. I am going to use being replaced or being retained it the table. Thank you so much. 

Comment: You're welcome! Yes that sounds good! Sounds fun :)

Comment: Smiles from Bali 

Comment: Thank you. I traveled Nusa Dua beach before. It was amazing. 

Comment: Oh really?! I have been to Tokyo, Kyota and Nara, it was wonderful...

Comment: I am glad to hear that. I am working at Tokyo now. Someday I would like to go to Bali Island again. It's was really fun. 

Comment: Yes it's a lovely place 

Answer (score 3):

You are going to [retain](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/retain) those components.

> 4. to hold in position

Comment: I thought of *retain* also, but not necessarily in the limited sense you provide - you should expand it.

Answer (score 0):

You could stay to keep it *static*

Answer (score -1):

How about **refresh**?

MW:

[**refresh**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refresh): To update or renew (something, such as an image, a display screen, or the contents of a computer memory) especially by sending a new signal.

**Refresh** can apply to both software and hardware, and it need not apply to all components at the same time.